# $image = "mystaticsite:v1" bash: =: command not found azure cloud shell bash

Tags: azure

```
majid@Azure:~$ $image = "mystaticsite:v1"
bash: =: command not found
```

This command is not working in azure cloud shell. Can anyone explain why what might be?

Answer (score 2):

Just to add to Charles Xu's answer, the shell is probably set to Bash but you need PowerShell for that command. You can change it in the top left dropdown of the Azure Cloud Shell:

[image: Cloud Shell Terminal Type Dropdown]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the variable definition is not right for bash in Linux, it's for PowerShell in Windows.

To define a variable in bash in Linux, the format should be like this:

```
image="mystaticsite:v1"
```